# What WinForms control corresponds to a VCL (Delphi) TControlBar?

Tags: .net, winforms, delphi, toolstrip

I need a WinForms control that will allow me to add control such as Images and Buttons to it. Preferably the height should be "stretchable," too - I'm trying a ToolStrip control, and it won't allow me to change its height.

Should I be using a Panel instead? Or something else altogether?

It must be a native component; we're avoiding 3rd party stuff like the plague.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Delphi stuff, what is the purpose of this control other than as a container?  If it's just a container, you could use a Panel, but you could also just place the controls directly on the form.

Comment: It autosizes based on what it contains, so you'd stretch images and buttons and the control will sort itelf out. Save yourself a lot of heartache, use the vanilla options, don't try and reinvent TControlBar

Comment: ToolstripLabel and ToolstripButton don't seem to be stretchable - if I change their dimensions in the property editor, it just blithely changes them back with nary a how-de-do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VCL [TControlBar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TControlBar) is basically a docking site for a [TToolBar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar) or another controls,  a [ToolStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is more like a VCL TToolBar so in your case the more similar component can be a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).